Should there be a nut on the inside of the rim? On a Schrader valve to a bicycle tube.?
I recently bought a specialized bike for my granddaughter and I had to patch the inner tube on the rear wheel. When I took it apart, I found a nut on the valve stem inside the rim. I have never seen this before, And was wondering if this was the correct location for the nut.

Can you see if this answered question applies to you? It applies to Presta tubes used with rims drilled for Schrader valves.

Can you take a picture and upload it? I've personally never even seen a Schrader valve that had threads far enough down the valve stem to have a nut inside the rim.

Does the nut and valve kind of look like this?  
If so that nut should go on the outside of the rim.  It helps hold the value in place on replacement and can be removed after everything is back together and the tube inflated.
It should be left in place if you let the pressure get low enough for the tube to shift (not advised), but should be removed if you ride frequently, keep your tires up to pressure and spent money on carbon wheels.  Its a few grams or rolling resistance.
I guess this nut also allows a presta valve to be used with a schrader rim and then the nut should be left in place.

You can always leave the ring in place, it does not hurt.

Threaded schrader valve stems definitely exist.  They're not common, but Schwalbe certainly make these.  Personally I like them.
It is possible the person who installed this tube simply didn't know any better, and assumed the nut was in the right place already.
It's also conceivable that this rim is a little sharp on the valve hole, and has a habit of cutting through tubes here.  The nut might have been left there to protect the tube from the rim instead of filing it smooth.
There may have been a second nut on the outside or not, but the bulk of schrader tubes cope fine without a retention nut.
Regardless, unless the puncture was right there at the valve stem, it has worked fine and you could choose to reinstall as it was, or put the nut on the outside, or do away with the nut.
Aside - small chance that someone has tried to "balance" the wheel but generally the valve is the heaviest part on the rim, and I'd expect to find a tiny balancing weight on the opposite side.   So having the extra nut at the valve is unlikely to be for balancing.   When I balance a rim I use plastic clip-on spoke reflectors that weigh a few grams at most.
